# Подсказки при вводе адреса перекрывают поле ввода

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добавил яндекс-карту на сайт. При вводе адреса назначения всплывающая подсказка перекрывает поле ввода. Как это исправить? Может размер iframe неудачный или есть какая-то настройка специальная?
[image: пример перекрывания поля ввода адреса]

Comment: Покажите страницу, на которой воспроизводится проблема.

Comment: http://tkrov.com/produkcija/teploizoljacija/pir/pir-plita-bitum.html

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у вас скрыты копирайты на карте, это запрещено [условиями использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/). Увеличьте размер `iframe`, чтобы их было видно.

Проблема с подсказками возникает из-за отступов. Добавьте `margin: 0` на `body` и `margin-top: 0` на первый `h1` во фрейме. Апи сейчас некорректно работает с такими отступами .

Comment: Спасибо огромное) На тестовой странице сделал, ошибка ушла. Копирайт тоже поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

Такая ситуация может возникнуть например если вы отлаживаете свой код на WordPress и у вас открыта админпанель. При разлогинивании проблема уходит.
Т.е. проблема с наличием на странице элементов с определенными CSS свойствами position